# Apache2 user (www-data) permission denied for folder owned by www-data

Tags: linux, silverstripe

I am using FreeNAS and have mounted a volume onto a VM I am running. I have a silverstripe website running in this VM with everything on this volume and everything is working fine, except the web server can't access my assets folder (permission denied). phpinfo returns that the apache user is www-data. ls -la returns that the uid and gid for the assets folder and everything in it are both www-data and permissions are set to 777. I can upload files into the assets folder through the silverstripe cms (which sets perms to -rw-r--r-- if that matters), but I cannot link to anything inside the assets folder.

Any help would be great!

Comment: So you get "Permission denied" when you visit a file directly like "website.com/assets/test.jpg"? But the CMS can access assets and write them?

Comment: Oh I just realized something. So I can access the files like that, where it fails is when I'm trying to download a file from the assets folder through a link on one of the pages. The issue is that the file is not actually being linked to so its just trying to access the /assets folder not the file in it. So it's a linking issue :/

Comment: How are you calling the image link in your template?

Comment: It was an error in the database build. So the links just weren't resolving. I dropped and recreated the database and things started going again :)

Answer (score 0):

So the error was due to an incorrect build of the database, leading to file paths not being resolved. So instead of linking to the files in my assets folder, it was trying to go to the assets/ directory which is why I was getting the error. I dropped and recreated the database and the links started working correctly again. Thanks for the help anyway everyone!

Comment: glad you got it working. please accept your own answer so the question is closed